# Is there a standard notation for the pre-composition operator?

Tags: category-theory, notation, terminology, function-and-relation-composition, lambda-calculus

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $V$ be sets. Is there a standard name and a standard notation for the pre-composition operator $F$ that takes as input a function $\varphi:X_2^{X_1}$ and returns the operator $F_{\varphi}:V^{X_2}\rightarrow V^{X_1}$, which assigns for every function $f:V^{X_2}$ the function $F_{\varphi}(f)\in V^{X_1}$ defined by
$$
F_{\varphi}(f) := f\circ\varphi
$$

Is this what is meant by the term *pullback* in category theory? And, again, is there a standard notation for designating $F$, given $X_1$, $X_2$, and $V$?

Comment: $V^f$ and $\varphi^*$ are common names for $F_\varphi$. Occasionally $\varphi^{-1}$ too.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thanks. What is it called?

Comment: I would write it as $(\circ \varphi)$ - this notation is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In category theory, this would be denoted $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{Set}(-,V)$, or simply $\mathbf{Set}(-,V)$. It's called the "contravariant hom-functor." That makes sense; given a function $$f : X_1 \rightarrow X_2,$$ we get a corresponding function $$\mathbf{Set}(f,V) : \mathbf{Set}(X_2,V) \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}(X_1,V)$$ going "the other way", defined by $$\mathbf{Set}(f,V)(g) = g \circ f.$$

Comment: Note that this is the same idea as the $V^f$ suggested by Hurkyl in the comments.

Comment: @ArnaudD., good point.

Comment: @ArnaudD.: In what field is the notation $V^f$ used? If I wish to look it up in a textbook, what kind of textbook should I seek?

Comment: @EvanAad It's also widely used in category theory. In general category theorists are happy to denote the action of any functor by plugging a morphism symbol in place of an object. Any book on category theory will have examples similar to this one.